# Why is intent.getStringExtra always null?

Tags: android, android-intent

I've looked and looked. Tried many things but nothing returns the data (regardless that it's present)

The information is being passed as: -> NOTE I posted wrong snippet, see below

```
userLists.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                Intent DisplayItems = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Items.class);
                Map<String,String> storeMap = lst.get(pos);
                DisplayItems.putExtra("id", storeMap.get("id"));
                startActivityForResult(DisplayItems, 1);
            }

        });
```

Received in onCreate:

```
groupIntent = getIntent();
        if(groupIntent.hasExtra("groupid")) {
            groupId = groupIntent.getStringExtra("groupid");
            resultCode = 2;
        }
```

groupId always returns null. In the debug groupIntent -> mExtras -> mMap -> value[0] = 5c00a086d45213.24138362 is displayed. All other classes pass and receive the intent as intended..

EDIT: My bad.. This is what actually inserts the extra

```
public void btnCreateList_Click(View view) {
        Intent createList = new Intent(context, CreateList.class);
        if(groupId!=null) {
            String grp = groupId;
            createList.putExtra("groupid", grp);
        }
        startActivityForResult(createList, 1);
    }
```

Comment: in Received in onCreate replace "groupid" with "id".So that it will work

Comment: groupId = groupIntent.getStringExtra("id"); your both key name is different

Comment: I posted the wrong code. It starts the intent from the button click not event listener

Comment: Can you confirm that the condition `groupId != null` is `true`?

Comment: it is, grp is also defined with the id above

Comment: was that activity started before? Is it in background?

Comment: No, although there is an onNewIntent handle present. I haven't seen it called before

Answer (score 1):

The code should be like below:

```
groupIntent = getIntent();
            if(groupIntent.hasExtra("id")) {
                groupId = groupIntent.getStringExtra("id");
                resultCode = 2;
            }
```